# Android build failing during soong bootsrap -- uses all resources and hangs

Tags: android, memory, gnu-make, ubuntu-18.04, android-soong

I'm building AOSP11 and building on Ubuntu 18.04 and early in the build process
I get the following error:

soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

It fails during this step:

out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja

It runs for about 1:15 and then the entire system hangs. When running the system
performance monitor I see that all available CPU (all cores) and memory is used
at the point it hangs. Dmesg shows an out-of-memory error.

```
[  18984] 637467462 18984   655554    79950  1187840        0             0 soong_uiJun 22 18:13:11 u4002491698b25b kernel: [30273.095111] [  20075] 637467462 20075     7301       94   102400        0             0 nsjail
Jun 22 18:13:11 u4002491698b25b kernel: [30273.095113] [  20076] 637467462 20076    18361     1104   131072        0             0 ninja
Jun 22 18:13:11 u4002491698b25b kernel: [30273.095114] [  22876] 637467462 22876     1159       17    53248        0             0 sh
Jun 22 18:13:11 u4002491698b25b kernel: [30273.095116] [  22877] 637467462 22877  3498675  3378317 27357184        0             0 soong_build
Jun 22 18:13:11 u4002491698b25b kernel: [30273.095116] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=soong_build,pid=22877,uid=637467462
Jun 22 18:13:11 u4002491698b25b kernel: [30273.095187] Out of memory: Killed process 22877 (soong_build) total-vm:13994700kB, anon-rss:13513268kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:637467462 pgtables:26716kB oom_score_ad
```

Searching the web shows that I should try using a lower -j value. I tried using -j1 or -j2 but the error still occurs. Sometimes, it will complete if I try it over and over
again but the number of times varies.

I'm using make 4.1 and have 16 GB of RAM. Builds are performed on an SSD via a gnome terminal.

I've tried removing the entire "out" directory along with "make clean" and nothing seems to help.

Would more memory help?

EDIT: The following is from verbose.log.1 and shows the failing command:

`[221/221] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm building AOSP 10 on Ubuntu 20.04.
When I don't pass the lower -j value and PC runs out of memory, the symptoms are the same. And my colleagues experience the same behavior - we noticed that running `make -j1` (or `m -j1`) several times ultimately leads to a successful build.

Or alternatively: first, you run `make`; after failure, you run `make -j1`.

So according to our experience, I assume more RAM should help as in your case AOSP 11 may occupy even more resources.